# How to make a record of multiple data types in java?

Tags: java, arrays, record

(using Netbeans)

I want to make something with an index like an array does, that when called will return multiple pieces of information which were previously inserted by the user.

```
e.g
name = Luke;
age = 20;
favouriteColour = red;
```

I have tried multiple arrays, maps/hashmaps (please someone explain these aswell, I have no clue), and despite it kind of working, it's like I've just thrown spaghetti at the screen.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just an `ArrayList<Person> people` where `Person` has methods `getName()`, `getAge()`, `getFavouriteColour()`? Then `people.get(i).getName()` would be Luke, etc.

Comment: You'll have to expand on that, I am quite new (if you hadn't guessed)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is an Object, just create a class yourself. For example:

```
public class Person
{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private Color favoriteColor;

    public Person(){
        // perhaps add some defaults here
    }

    public void setName(String n){
        name = n;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setAge(int a){
        age = a;
    }

    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }

    public void setFavoriteColor(Color c){
        favoriteColor = c;
    }

    public Color getFavoriteColor(){
        return favoriteColor;
    }
}
```

In your main app you can then create this Object like so:

```
Person person = new Person();
```

Store the user inputs in it. So when the user adds a name:

```
person.setName(nameThatWasInputtedByTheUser);
```

You can store all of these UserInputContainers in a list:

```
ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>(); // or "new ArrayList<>();" when you use Java 8.0+
```

Then at the end you can get all this again like so:

```
System.out.println("Person at index " + index);
Person currentPerson = list.get(index);
System.out.println("Name: " + currentPerson.getName());
System.out.println("Age: " + currentPerson.getAge());
System.out.println("Color: " + currentPerson.getColor());
```